# Regex getting number from string that stops at _ and str after _ underscore

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, numbers

I have several strings that look like this:

```
str1 = "C:/Users/10MedicineA\20072018_medicineName_00222_01111"
str2 = "C:/Users/MedicineB\21072018_medicineName_03333_01121"
```

I need to extract the digits after the backslash (supposed to be the date) and the `medicineName` as well as the identifier (which is the first number series after the "medicineName".

So the final result should look like:

```
['20072018','medicineName','00222']
```

How is it possible to get everything after the backslash `\` till the underscore `_`?

I would like to do it with regex, and of course its easy to filter the `C:/Users/` part, cause its always the same, but thats not true for the rest:

```
final = re.findall(r'\d+\.*',str1)
['10','20072018','00222','01111']
```

or

```
final = re.findall(r'(?=[0-9]).*(?=\_)')
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to do it with regex? There are simpler ways.

Comment: is `medicineName` always there? or can be any string?

Comment: Just a note: you will need to use double backslashes (`\\`) in a string literal because you need to use the first to escape the second

Comment: the reason for regex is that the strings are indeed not always the same. Therefore, I want to avoid errors, if some numbers are longer than expected. Also, `medicineName` is not always the same AND `medicineName` can include numbers as well - thats why I like to split at `_` but also drop the last number in case a file is stored as "version 2" or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this expression might likely return the desired output:

```
.*\\|(.+?)_
```

which would collect all chars upto the last `\`, then using this capturing group `(.+?)` would return our desired outputs, and simultaneously excludes the last undesired substring after the `_`.

---

If you wish to find the first three substrings before `_`, this expression might work:

```
\\([^\\_\s]+)_([^\\_\s]+)_([^\\_\s]+)_
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"\\([^\\_\s]+)_([^\\_\s]+)_([^\\_\s]+)_"

test_str = ("C:/Users/10MedicineA\\20072018_medicineName_00222_01111\n"
    "C:/Users/MedicineB\\21072018_medicineName_03333_01121\n"
    "Users/3A Medicine\\\\200726_21-PQmed_00223_07_01110")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/m0huTb/1/)

Comment: `.*\\|(.+?)_` did work the best for me. Idk why, but `(\d+)_([^_]*)_(\d+)_` sometimes fails for some strings since some files/strings are poorly named like `Users/3A Medicine\\200726_21-PQmed_00223_07_01110`

Comment: @Felix you didn't specify what should happen in this case

Comment: In this case, it should give you a list like `list = ["200726","21-PQmed","00223"]` .. currently, trying to figure it out lol

Comment: @Felix well in that case my [pattern works](https://regex101.com/r/m0huTb/2) just fine. just sayin'...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with regex, you could do something like:

```py
import re

strings = ["C:/Users/10MedicineA/20072018_medicineName_00222_01111",
           "C:/Users/MedicineB/21072018_medicineName_03333_01121"]

for s in strings:
    r = re.search(r"(\d+)_(medicineName)_(\d+)_", str1)
    if r:
        print(list(r.groups()))
```

And this gives:

```
['20072018', 'medicineName', '00222']
['21072018', 'medicineName', '03333']
```

If you want to cover more general options change to:

```
"(\d+)_([^_]*)_(\d+)_"
```

---

Considering that your strings are paths, you could also use `pathlib` for that task:

```py
from pathlib import Path

s = "C:/Users/10MedicineA/20072018_medicineName_00222_01111"

last_part = Path(s).name
print(last_part.split("_")[:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```py
import re

str1 = "C:/Users/10MedicineA\20072018_medicineName_00222_01111"
str2 = "C:/Users/MedicineB\21072018_medicineName_03333_01121"

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)_([^_\s]*)_(\d+)')

print(list(pattern.search(str1).groups()))
# ['72018', 'medicineName', '00222']

print(list(pattern.search(str2).groups()))
# ['72018', 'medicineName', '03333']
```

Here is the visualization of my regex pattern.

[image]